# How do I perform Erosion and or Dilation on a OpenCvSharp.Mat file?

Tags: c#, opencv

I use a converted picture (**from System.Drawing.Image** to **OpenCvSharp.Mat**) in **C#** to do some **processing**:

```
// convert (Image -> Mat)
Mat prepImg = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(new Bitmap(this.originalImage));

// to grayscale
prepImg = prepImg .CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);

// binarize
prepImg = prepImg .Threshold(90, 255, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv);
```

Now how do I perform an **erosion** or an **dilation** on prepImg ?
The methods (**erode()** and **dilate()**) seem to expect an **InputArray** element - is this the **kernel**?

Tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Mat kernel = new Mat(1);

// input array
InputArray inArr = new InputArray(kernel);

// erode
prepImg = prepImg .Erode(inArr );

// dilate
prepImg = prepImg .Dilate(inArr );
```

**Note**: I use the Mat format in ordner to be able to use it with the Cv2 Methods. (Need to remove some thin lines in order to prepare the binarized image for tesseract OCR)